# taking the Swing UI to next level?

Tags: java, swing

i have designed an application using java swing, how to improve the look and feel and User interface?

Answer (score 5):

It depends upon your objective.

- If you want to go in the desktop way, maybe by using some of [Kirill Grouchnikov](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/) works : [Substance LnF](https://substance.dev.java.net/) and [Flamingo](https://flamingo.dev.java.net/) (which emulates the Office ribbon using Swing code)
- If you want to go in the pimp'd direction, take a look at old works of [Chet Haase and Romain Guy](http://filthyrichclients.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps change the look and feel to something more "native": http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 1):

While the question is very vague....I'll provide an obvious quick tip.

Make sure to handle events and/or heavy processing on a background thread.
[SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is now included in the Java 6 JRE/JDK

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //some task

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
           //when done
           }


        };

        threadPool.submit(worker);
```